# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Flutter": In Podfile: Flutter (from `Flutter`)

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

After upgrade to flutter 3.1, I can build and run for android but I got the following error for ios. May I know what is the reason for this issue?

```
Aungs-MBP:ios aungmyooo$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
firebase_analytics: Using Firebase SDK version '8.15.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '8.15.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
Warning: firebase_app_id_file.json file does not exist. This may cause issues in upload-symbols. If this error is unexpected, try running flutterfire configure again.
firebase_crashlytics: Using Firebase SDK version '8.15.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '8.15.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Flutter":
  In Podfile:
    Flutter (from `Flutter`)

Specs satisfying the `Flutter (from `Flutter`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

> [✓] Flutter (Channel master, 3.1.0-0.0.pre.1279, on macOS 12.4 21F79
> darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
> • Flutter version 3.1.0-0.0.pre.1279 at /Users/aungmyooo/Development/flutter
> • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
> • Framework revision ddeb0b99c5 (18 hours ago), 2022-06-16 13:53:23 -0700
> • Engine revision f8c0dc87bc
> • Dart version 2.18.0 (build 2.18.0-189.0.dev)
> • DevTools version 2.14.0
>
> [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 31.0.0)
> • Android SDK at /Users/aungmyooo/Library/Android/sdk
> • Platform android-32, build-tools 31.0.0
> • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)
> • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4.1)
> • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
> • CocoaPods version 1.11.3
>
> [✓] Chrome - develop for the web
> • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
>
> [✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
> • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
> • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
>  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
> • Dart plugin can be installed from:
>  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)
>
> [✓] VS Code (version 1.68.1)
> • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
> • Flutter extension version 3.42.0
>
> [✓] Connected device (3 available)
> • SM N975F (mobile) • RF8M82Y3K9A • android-arm64  • Android 12 (API 31)
> • macOS (desktop)   • macos       • darwin-x64     • macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-x64
> • Chrome (web)      • chrome      • web-javascript • Google Chrome 102.0.5005.115
>
> [✓] HTTP Host Availability
> • All required HTTP hosts are available
>
> • No issues found!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In the ios folder -> PodFile. You will see that the version of platform is 9 and is commented. Please uncomment it and set the version to 11.0

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'
```

**EDIT - 2024**

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.0'
```

Comment: Actually, platform :ios, '10.0' and I update it to 11. And then It work. So flutter 3.0 only support ios 11?

Comment: Yeah it works on 11

Comment: Here didn't work. So I updated flutter and when I run it auto updated to 12. 2024 answer.

Comment: platform :ios, '13.0' - 2024